# Angular.js : prettyPhoto URL redirected to default page mentioned in angular route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, prettyphoto

When I click any image associate with `prettyPhoto` Plugin, The URL of the browser get changed to `example.com/#/prettyPhoto[residential1]/0/` and get redirect to the route that's defined in `.otherwise({..})`

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            title: 'Home',
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
            controller: 'PageCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });
}]);
```

Can I do something like I mentioned below, eg: anything that defined after `/prettyPhoto*******` should redirected to `/projects`:

```
.when('/prettyPhoto[*anyArray*]/*anyNumber*/', {
            redirectTo: '/projects'
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the doc, It says :

> Route path (matched against $location.path). If $location.path contains redundant trailing slash or is missing one, the route will still match and the $location.path will be updated to add or drop the trailing slash to exactly match the route definition.
>
> **Path can contain named groups starting with a colon**: e.g. ***:name***. All characters up to the next slash are matched and stored in $routeParams under the given name when the route matches.
>   path can contain named groups starting with a colon and ending with a star: e.g.:name*. All characters are eagerly stored in $routeParams under the given name when the route matches.
>   path can contain optional named groups with a question mark: e.g.:name?.
>
> For example, routes like /color/:color/largecode/:largecode*/edit will match /color/brown/largecode/code/with/slashes/edit and extract:

So if i use what it says, your code becomes :

```
.when('/prettyPhoto:anyArray/:anyNumber', {
        redirectTo: '/projects'
})
```

Doc : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

I hope my answer fit you :)

Comment: I just did **.when('/prettyPhoto:array/:number', {redirectTo: '/projects'})** and my problem got fixed, thanks :) @Aliz

Answer (score 0):

Set deeplinking : false wherever you have initialised the prettyPhoto

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
      animation_speed:'normal',
      slideshow:5000,
      autoplay_slideshow: false,
      overlay_gallery: true,
      deeplinking: false,
      social_tools: false
    });
```